# Calculation Server Architecture

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, master-slave

I have a rails app. This app takes parameters from the users and sends it to what I think would be called a slave application server that runs heavy calculations in Python. This slave server is located on the same physical box and runs a Python "SimpleHTTPServer" (just a basic web server).

I set up the slave to receive commands through post requests and run the calculations. Is it appropriate for the python server to receive these requests through GET/POST even though it is on the same box or should I be using another protocol?

**note I have looked into rubypython and other direct connectors but I need a separate app server to run calculations.

Comment: It's perfectly appropriate to setup a HTTP REST based communication with your microservices. But there is a discussion on REST vs Message system. The best approach depends on your requirement.